# Getting SocketTimeoutException sometimes when running tomcat server inside docker

Tags: docker, tomcat7

I am running my application with tomcat and inside docker container. Everything works fine but sometimes I am getting SocketTimeoutException Read time out when accessing some urls.

```
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at com.gauss.forms.ui.util.DocumentSetUtil.postDocumentSet(DocumentSetUtil.java:595)
    at com.gauss.forms.ui.util.DocumentSetUtil.notifyDocumentSet_POST(DocumentSetUtil.java:518)
    at com.gauss.forms.action.type.util.ActionTypeUtil.doTheDocActionPost(ActionTypeUtil.java:990)
    at com.gauss.forms.action.type.util.ActionTypeUtil.resolveUrlAndDoTheDocActionPost(ActionTypeUtil.java:956)
    at com.gauss.forms.action.type.util.ActionTypeUtil.doDocAction(ActionTypeUtil.java:812)
    at com.gauss.forms.web.FormResource$2.handle(FormResource.java:991)
    at com.gauss.forms.core.Handler.doHandle(Handler.java:31)
    at com.gauss.forms.core.TransactedHandler.access$001(TransactedHandler.java:20)
    at com.gauss.forms.core.TransactedHandler$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactedHandler.java:29)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:34)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at com.gauss.forms.core.TransactedHandler.doHandle(TransactedHandler.java:25)
    at com.gauss.forms.core.Resource.doHandle(Resource.java:67)
    at com.gauss.forms.web.FormResource.doHandle(FormResource.java:1221)
    at com.gauss.forms.core.Resource.handle(Resource.java:55)
    at com.gauss.forms.core.Filter.handle(Filter.java:61)
    at com.gauss.forms.web.XHTMLCacheFilter.handle(XHTMLCacheFilter.java:196)
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04 to create docker container using bridge network. The docker machine is running on EC2.
**Note: I tried increasing connectionTimeout but that too didn't help.**

Comment: Can you provide more information about your Docker host environment, please? Is this running on bare metal, in a VM, EC2?

Comment: @ThatsNinja It is an EC2 instance.

Comment: Have you checked your CPU credit balances to make sure you don't have an EC2 instance that's pausing because it's exhausted its allotment of clock cycles? I've had this issue with multiple Java applications in particular.

Comment: Were you able to resolve?

Comment: No, not till now. Allotment of clock cycle is unlimited.